# wp_editor in thickbox

Tags: shortcode, ajax, tinymce, wp-editor

I am updating a shortcode generator that I made before and I want to add in addition to text areas inputs etc.. a tinymce editor, so I call wp_editor in the ajax content of the thickbox, the editor appears but without any buttons and when switching to visual tab I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,schedule,wp-ajax-response,autosave,jqu…:46
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post load-scripts.php?